# Is there a name for a sheaf where every germ extends to a global section?

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory

This is strictly weaker than being flasque -- consider, for instance, the case of the sheaf of smooth functions on a smooth manifold, which has this property but is not flasque.

Comment: _Soft_ sheaves have that property, but I think it is strictly weaker than being soft.

Comment: It's a very weak condition. For instance, consider a constant sheaf on a connected topological space that has at least two disjoint non-empty open subsets.